# directory layout of a Go-lang project?

Tags: go

I'm just discovering the [Go](http://golang.org/) programming language.

<sup>(FWIW, I am fluent in C++, Ocaml, C, Common Lisp, Scheme, I know well Linux, and I have designed & implemented [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/); I am considering a rewrite of some [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015) in Go, but have not decided it yet)</sup>

I am a bit confused about the required layout of some Go workspace. I still am unease with the notion of packages in Go (they seems similar to Ocaml's modules) and the interfaces in Go (they look like Ocaml's signatures or module types).

The [*How To Write Go Code*](https://tip.golang.org/doc/code.html) document mentions both a `pkg/` and a `src/` *mandatory* subdirectory, but Michael Maccanis' [Oh shell](https://github.com/michaelmacinnis/oh) example don't have any `src/` and I was still able to build it using the

```
 go get github.com/michaelmacinnis/oh
```

command mentionned in [its `README.md`](https://github.com/michaelmacinnis/oh/blob/master/README.md). **Why** (and how) **does that work** (without any `src/`) **?**

---

If that is important, I'm using go1.8rc2 on Linux/amd-64 (Debian/Sid). I'm trying Go right now (and did not look into it before) because [*Go 1.8*](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.8) (scheduled before spring 2017) should [have plugins](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.8#plugin) and these are a feature essential to me.

PS. I've read (and liked) the [Go for C++ programmer](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GoForCPPProgrammers) wiki; but I might miss the Go for Ocaml programmer equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you go get something, it is placed under the `$GOPATH/src` , in the respective folders, depending on what you import. That repo is `github.com/michaelmacinnis/oh`, so it is cloned to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/michaelmacinnis/oh`. In pkg, `$GOPATH/pkg/github.com/michaelmacinnis/oh`, the compiled shared objects for your platform resides, and they are reused for further compilations from other packages, if the source packages are not modified.

In short, the code should be in `$GOPATH/src/path/to/repo/code/etc/hi` , so when you go get, it puts `/path/to/repo/code/etc/hi` to `$GOPATH/src` , it is how go packages are resolved.